# Spring-boot not find css even the HTML file

Tags: spring-boot

First: the HTML shows all the css and it cannot be recognized:

Second: The project runs just localhost but just give me the following output and does not start port 8080:

```
2017-03-11 12:07:48.579  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-03-11 12:07:48.581  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-03-11 12:07:48.582  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-03-11 12:07:48.622  INFO 2397 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-03-11 12:07:48.748  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-03-11 12:07:49.046  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-03-11 12:07:49.047  INFO 2397 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-03-11 12:07:49.076  INFO 2397 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-11 12:07:49.544  INFO 2397 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-11 12:07:49.561  INFO 2397 --- [           main] com.brock.BrockApplication               : Started BrockApplication in 12.875 seconds (JVM running for 13.425)
2017-03-11 12:07:49.562  INFO 2397 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@21a947fe: startup date [Sat Mar 11 12:07:47 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-11 12:07:49.564  INFO 2397 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-03-11 12:07:49.564  INFO 2397 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-11 12:07:49.565  INFO 2397 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-03-11 12:07:49.565  INFO 2397 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete

Process finished with exit code 0
```

File structure:

[image]

In HomeController I have:

```
@Controller()
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

The JS and CSS file paths look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

According to the docs I put them in the correct place and it should return index.html.

-----------------Update 1----------------

applications.properities

```
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=- 1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=brock
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue causing the application to shut down immediately is caused by using **WAR** packaging, while running the application as a Spring boot application in IntelliJ.

Due to that, IntelliJ won't provide the necessary classes (because **spring-boot-starter-tomcat** has scope **provided**) and if it's missing, Spring boot won't know that it should run as a web application causing it to exit immediately.

To solve it either:

1. Comment the **provided** scope:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Run the application within **Tomcat**

---

When you fix the first problem, you still have another issue. You've placed your HTML files within the **src/main/resources/templates** folder, while this folder should only be used for dynamic templates (Thymeleaf, Freemarker, Groovy, Mustache, ...).

However, currently your HTML files are just plain, static HTML files, so you should put them in **src/main/resources/static**. If they aren't static HTML files, you should add a proper template engine, for example **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf**.

If you use static templates, Spring boot will automatically resolve `/` to your `index.html`, so you can delete `HomeController`.

---

Finally, you said you're using the following CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

This is the **right way** to do it. However, on [GitHub](https://github.com/drewjocham/Brock/blob/master/brock/src/main/resources/templates/index.html#L22) I noticed that you were using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/static/css/main.css">
```

This is not the right way. Even though the folder structures are correct, at runtime, Spring boot will run both `public/` as `templates/` on your context path root (`/`). This means that, even if you would have `index.html` in one folder and `css/main.css` in your other folder, it would still work.

Comment: FYI, since I started with cloning/modifying you repository, I've forked it and created a pull request. https://github.com/drewjocham/Brock/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

Can you annotate your HomeController class with @RestController annotation and deploy your app again

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a modelandview instead of raw string?

```
@RestController()
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `spring-boot-starter-web` to your dependencies will enable embedded tomcat as default servlet container and your application will be exposed on port `8080` by default.

Gradle:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have that. I think it is because I do not have my application.properties set up correctly. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Please show your `application.properties` then, we'll see what we can do.

Comment: OK, you haven't added a templating engine, that's the issue, just add `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` to your dependencies. Another issue is that your `index.html` file is **not valid** HTML file (you don't use html ending tags for `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<br>` or `img>`), take a look at: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/fromhtmltohtmlviahtml.html

Comment: I removed the tags and added the dependency and still the same issue. I bought this template but I cannot get it to render. Git updated and I am not using thymeleaf right now.

Comment: can you post your dependencies/pom.xml? Maybe it's one of the other dependencies that you are missing, because your app is now closing directly after it has started running

Answer (score 0):

Teena is right use `@RestController` or if you use  `@Controller` add the  `@ResponseBody` annotation

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```